# Glassfish 3.1 Maximum URI Length

Tags: glassfish, buffer-overflow, http-get

I'm having this error when using a long GET request:

> SEVERE: GRIZZLY0039: Request URI is
>   too large.
>   java.nio.BufferOverflowException

What is the configuration I have to change for Glassfish 3.1?

I tried changing these parameters but had no success :
- header-buffer-length-bytes (through admin console)
- request-body-buffer-size-bytes (in domain.xml)

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had the same problem while deploying a large application into a cluster (standalone deployment was working). A solution, that worked for us was to increase the TCP buffer size. 
In the administration console change 
'Configurations -> cluster-config -> Network Config -> Transports -> tcp -> Buffer Size' to 131072 or more.

Hope that helps. -- Wintermute